# How can I get the userIds of the people that installed my app after being referred by person X?

Tags: branch.io

How can I use the Branch.io API to get the userIds of all the people that installed my app after being referred by person X? I'm trying to credit person X for referring friends who bought a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the referral history API call and then parse the response to get the list of referred users. https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/#referral-history

Comment: do you know what field has the userid?

Comment: you should see them as referror or referree as long as you have used set identity. https://docs.branch.io/deep-linked-ads/criteo-mobile-tracking/#identifying-users-with-setidentity